# How to examine .torrent file?

Tags: bittorrent

I tried to examine the content of a .torrent file using a

$ od -c xyz.torrent

Some of the content of the file is in plain text like the information regarding the trackers, creation date, the encoding used,the length and the number of pieces but the rest is encoded. Can somebody please tell me how i can examine the torrent file so that i can decode everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.torrent` files are bencoded dictionaries](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#metainfo-files-are-bencoded-dictionaries-with-the-following-keys)
[More information](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding)

Answer (score 1):

Use **lstor** from the **pyroscope** package: https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/CommandLineTools#lstor

It pretty-prints the contents of .torrent files.